# Legends not displaying as of bar colors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I'm using core-plot0.4 for drawing waterfall graph. I have used barFillForBarPlot for coloring bars, but in legends(CPTLegend) its not displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Core Plot bug. Please report it on the [Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

Comment: This issue has been fixed. Pull the latest code with Mercurial to get the change.